# Android Spinner getView

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a custom adapter and using the getView method in attempt to display a default text only ONCE. Now I'm having a problem such that when I click the first Item in the list, the default text is kept but that doesn't hold for any other items? Any suggestions?

Thanks! (My code is a bit messy as I was just trying to debug)

```
boolean firstTime = true;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (firstTime) {
        firstTime = false;
        TextView firstView = new TextView(ForgotPasswordActivity.this);
        firstView.setText("Please select School");
        return firstView;
    }
    TextView view = new TextView(ForgotPasswordActivity.this);
    view.setText("Hello");
    return view;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"the default text is kept but that doesn't hold for any other items"_ your question is confusing.. please explain clearly

Answer (score 2):

You must play with the getCount function :

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount() -1; // This makes the trick;
}
```

this trick will not show last item that you've added inside your spinner(so when you finish adding your text inside the spinner, add the text that will not be shown in the spinner, and by that it will be show as a default value before clicking the spinner).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your trying to do but you could force the top row to always show the select message by checking if the position is 0. Also notice in the code below that I'm reusing the convertView if it is not null. It's faster to reuse the convertView if it is available than to recreate a new view every time.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = new TextView(ForgotPasswordActivity.this);
        }

        if(position == 0) {
            convertView.setText("Please select School");
        } else {
            convertView.setText("Hello");
        }

        return convertView;

    }
```

Also remember that by forcing position zero to show the select message you are not showing the actual data in the adapter at position 0. Make sure this is what you want to do or insert a dummy piece of data in the first position of the backing data array.